# Unknown left-behind tensors after calling dispose

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

As I have just started learning ML with TensorFlow.js, I want to get some hands-on experience and came up with the following code, which tries to solve the XOR problem (failed, of course).

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const dataset_train = [
    { a1: .2, a2: .1, a3: .65, b1: .35, b2: .55, result: 0 },
    { a1: .05, a2: 0, a3: .1, b1: .5, b2: .4, result: 1 },
    { a1: .8, a2: .15, a3: .05, b1: .15, b2: .1, result: 1 },
    { a1: 0, a2: .05, a3: .1, b1: .45, b2: .45, result: 1 },
    { a1: .15, a2: .05, a3: .75, b1: .4, b2: .35, result: 0 },
    { a1: .2, a2: .05, a3: 0, b1: .15, b2: 0, result: 0 },
    { a1: .1, a2: .1, a3: .05, b1: .65, b2: .25, result: 1 },
    { a1: .8, a2: 0, a3: .05, b1: .25, b2: .1, result: 1 },
    { a1: .15, a2: .05, a3: 0, b1: 0, b2: .15, result: 0 },
    { a1: .4, a2: .15, a3: .2, b1: .7, b2: .3, result: 0 }
];

const dataset_validation = [
    { a1: 0, a2: .15, a3: .1, b1: .25, b2: .7, result: 1 },
    { a1: .9, a2: .05, a3: 0, b1: .3, b2: .7, result: 0 },
    { a1: .15, a2: 0, a3: .05, b1: .2, b2: .1, result: 0 },
    { a1: .6, a2: .25, a3: .1, b1: .05, b2: 0, result: 1 },
    { a1: .05, a2: .45, a3: .35, b1: .6, b2: .3, result: 0 }
];

const dataset_test = [
    { a1: .25, a2: .5, a3: .15, b1: .05, b2: .1 },
    { a1: .05, a2: 0, a3: 0, b1: .8, b2: 0 },
    { a1: 0, a2: .1, a3: .05, b1: .1, b2: .15 },
    { a1: .3, a2: .45, a3: .25, b1: .25, b2: .7 },
    { a1: 0, a2: .15, a3: 0, b1: .45, b2: .35 }
];

const input_1 = tf.input({ shape: [3] });
const input_2 = tf.input({ shape: [2] });

const layer_1_1 = tf.layers.dense({ units: 3, activation: 'sigmoid' }).apply(input_1);
const layer_1_2 = tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, activation: 'sigmoid' }).apply(input_2);
const layer_2_1 = tf.layers.concatenate().apply([layer_1_1, layer_1_2]);
const layer_3_1 = tf.layers.dense({ units: 5, activation: 'sigmoid' }).apply(layer_2_1);
const layer_4_1 = tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'sigmoid' }).apply(layer_3_1);

const model = tf.model({ inputs: [input_1, input_2], outputs: layer_4_1 });

const x_train_1 = tf.tensor(dataset_train.map(d => [d.a1, d.a2, d.a3]));
const x_train_2 = tf.tensor(dataset_train.map(d => [d.b1, d.b2]));
const y_train = tf.tensor(dataset_train.map(d => [d.result]));

const x_valid_1 = tf.tensor(dataset_validation.map(d => [d.a1, d.a2, d.a3]));
const x_valid_2 = tf.tensor(dataset_validation.map(d => [d.b1, d.b2]));
const y_valid = tf.tensor(dataset_validation.map(d => [d.result]));

const x_test_1 = tf.tensor(dataset_test.map(d => [d.a1, d.a2, d.a3]));
const x_test_2 = tf.tensor(dataset_test.map(d => [d.b1, d.b2]));

const tensors = [
    x_train_1,
    x_train_2,
    y_train,
    x_valid_1,
    x_valid_2,
    y_valid,
    x_test_1,
    x_test_2
];

model.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });
model.fit([x_train_1, x_train_2], y_train, {
    epochs: 1000,
    batchSize: 20,
    shuffle: true,
    validationData: [[x_valid_1, x_valid_2], y_valid]
}).then(() => {
    model.predict([x_test_1, x_test_2]).print();

    for (let i = 0; i < tensors.length; ++i) {
        tensors[i].dispose();
    }
    tf.disposeVariables();

    // 2 tensors are still lingering somewhere...
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(tf.memory())}`);
});
```

The code is executed in a Node.js console on my Windows 10 machine. After the prediction is made, memory usage is printed to the console as shown below.

`{"unreliable":true,"numTensors":2,"numDataBuffers":2,"numBytes":24}`

- What is the source of these left-behind tensors?
- How can I deal with it?

Comment: did you try model.dispose() after predict?

Comment: @CrazyBrazilian Tried adding `model.dispose();` right after `model.predict(...).print();`, still gave me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When you called `model.predict(...)` you created a new tensor that needs to be disposed (even though you didn't assign it to as a variable).  I believe that the other one corresponds with your model. Note that when you call `.dispose()` on your model, you don't need to also call `tf.disposeVariables()`. I reran your code with these changes:

```
const output = model.predict([x_test_1, x_test_2]);
output.print();

output.dispose();  <---
model.dispose();   <---

for (let i = 0; i < tensors.length; ++i) {
    tensors[i].dispose();
}

console.log(`${JSON.stringify(tf.memory())}`);
```

This produced the following output:

```
{"unreliable":true,"numTensors":0,"numDataBuffers":0,"numBytes":0}
```